Application of a theorem of Montel
I have the following problem:
Let $\mathcal{F}=\{f:B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}: f(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n}$ and $|a_n|\leq n^3\}$. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal.
My approach so far: I would like to apply one theorem of Montel which says that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal iff $\mathcal{F}$ is locally bounded. So fix $z_0\in B_1(0)$ and $r>0$ such that $\overline{B_r(z_0)}\subset B_1(0)$. Let $f\in \mathcal{F}$. We'd like to show that $||f||_{\overline{B_r(z_0)}}=$sup$\{|f(x)|x\in B_r(z_0)\}\leq m$ for some $m>0$ for any $f\in \mathcal{F}$. If my understanding is correct, we must find some $m$ that works for every function in $\mathcal{F}$ on the closed ball. Since
$||f||_{\overline{B_r(z_0)}}=$sup$\Big{\{} |\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n}|  : z\in \overline{B_r(z_0)} $ and $|a_n|\leq n^3\Big{\}}\leq $sup$\Big{\{} \displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n||z|^n}  : z\in \overline{B_r(z_0)} $ and $|a_n|\leq n^3\Big{\}}\leq $sup$\Big{\{} \displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3|z|^n}  : z\in \overline{B_r(z_0)} \Big{\}}$
Next, notice that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^3|z|^n}$ converges by the ratio test since $|z|<1$, as $\overline{B_r(z_0)}\subset B_1(0)$. In particular, it converges to some $m>0$ and $||f||_{\overline{B_r(z_0)}}\leq m$.
My concern is the following: does this $m$ work for every $f\in \mathcal{F}$, or just for this specific function? Will each function from $\mathcal{F}$ come with its own $m_f$ and a further argument needs to be made that these $m_f$'s are all bounded by some further $M$? Any advice would be appreciated!

You used nothing special about any particular $f$ to get $m$, just the bound $|a_n| \le n^3$, so the same $m$ will work for all $f \in \mathcal F$.
